# How to save form data into list and then display list to another page in Angular?

Tags: angular, list, forms

[image]

When I click Yes i want my data to be stored in a list. That List i want to display on another page.

When i console.log my data it looks like this:

[image]

Can someone help? Im new to Angular. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take the help of APIs
first create a file called db.json

```
{"posts": [] ,"signup":[]}
```

import the api and http

```
import { ApiService } from '../shared/api.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

**signup.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  fullname:[''],
  email:[''],
  password:[''],
  mobile:['']
})}

signUp(){
this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:3000/signupUsers", this.signupForm?.value)
.subscribe(res=>{
  alert("Sign Up Is Done Succesfully");
  this.signupForm?.reset();
  this.router.navigate(['login']);
},err=>{
  alert("Something went wrong")

})}
```

now to get the data use

```
getStudentDetails(){      // get Api Done
this.api.getStudents().subscribe(res=>{
  this.studentData = res;
})
```

but ensure that create new file called **model.ts**

```
export class StudentModel{
id:number=0;
name:string="";
roll:number=0;
email:string="";
mobile:number=0;
salary:number=0;
wishlist : boolean = false;
complete: any;
}
```

and at last install the json server
**npm install -g json-server**

and run the json server

**json-server --watch db.json**

so you can display the data in another page

```
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let student of studentData">
  <tr *ngIf="student.complete">
    <td>{{student.email}}</td>
    <td>{{student.phone}}</td>
    <td>{{student.address}}</td>
    <td>{{student.salary}}</td>
  </tr>
```